# Top users page doesn't include upvotes if no answers made

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, top-users

I've not been posting on SO recently as I've been focusing on various StackExchange sites including my own, but I've been regularly checking in to see how my reputation is ticking along.

I just checked the [maven-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=maven-2&sort=stats&pagesize=30) stats page and my recent reputation and realised I've had around 16 upvotes for maven-2 since Jan 1st, but am not in the "Last 30 days" list. I guess this is because I've made 0 answers.

I'm not even sure I'd call this a bug as I haven't posted any answers in the last 30 days, just thought it might be of interest. Or not.

As requested, here are a few maven-2 answers I've had upvoted in the last week or two. I can add more if needed.

- [Why use Gradle instead of Ant or Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163173/why-use-gradle-instead-of-ant-or-maven/1165553#1165553)
- [Maven creating flat zip assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500758/maven-creating-flat-zip-assembly/1500919#1500919)
- [How do I tell Maven to use the latest version of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571/how-do-i-tell-maven-to-use-the-latest-version-of-a-dependency/1172371#1172371)
- [How to build without using locally installed artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171806/how-to-build-without-using-locally-installed-artifacts/1171874#1171874)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you provide a link to one or two answers that have received recent upvotes, so that those with magical ninja DB access powers can look into what happened?

Comment: @Æther, examples added

Answer (score 1):

How is this a bug? If the answers weren't provided in the last 30 days, they're not eligible for the "last 30 days" part of that statistics page...

Comment: Technically, it is the number of 'Answers' you have provided in the past 30 days . Not just the number of 'Upvotes' you have. Not sure how this is a bug either.

Comment: Interesting, I always interpreted the 30 days time period to be when the upvote had to have been received, not the time when the post was originally made.

Comment: I didn't say it was a bug, the bug tag was edited in. However if I post a single answer that gets no upvotes I suspect I'll suddenly be second in the list anyway due to my 16 votes. So there is some inconsistency.